# Simple web-scraper in Common Lisp (SBCL)

Tags: common-lisp

I have written a simple web-scraper in Common Lisp, & would greatly appreciate any feedback:

```
(defpackage :myfitnessdata
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:export #:main))

(in-package :myfitnessdata)

(require :sb-posix)
(load (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp" (user-homedir-pathname)))
(ql:quickload '("drakma" 
        "closure-html" 
        "cxml-stp" 
        "net-telent-date"))

(defun show-usage () 
  (format t "MyFitnessData - a CSV web scraper for the MyFitnessPal website.~%")
  ;; snip
  (format t "'c:\\Users\\bob\\weights.csv', overwriting it if it exists.~%"))

(defun login (username password)
  "Logs in to www.myfitnesspal.com.  Returns a cookie-jar containing authentication details."
  (let ((cookie-jar (make-instance 'drakma:cookie-jar)))
    (drakma:http-request "http://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/login"
             :method :post
             :parameters `(("username" . ,username) ("password" . ,password))
             :cookie-jar cookie-jar)
    cookie-jar))

(defun logged-in? (cookie-jar)       
  "Returns true if a cookie-jar contains login information for www.myfitnesspal.com, and nil otherwise."
  (let ((logged-in? nil))
    (loop for cookie in (drakma:cookie-jar-cookies cookie-jar) do
      (if (and (equal (drakma:cookie-name cookie) "known_user")
           (equal (drakma:cookie-domain cookie) "www.myfitnesspal.com")
           (drakma:cookie-value cookie))
          (setq logged-in? t)))
    logged-in?))

(defun get-page (page-num cookie-jar)
  "Downloads a potentially invalid HTML page containing data to scrape.  Returns a string containing the HTML."
  (let ((url (concatenate 'string "http://www.myfitnesspal.com/measurements/edit?type=1&page=" (write-to-string page-num))))
    (let ((body (drakma:http-request url :cookie-jar cookie-jar)))
      (if (search "No measurements found." body)
      nil
    body))))

(defun scrape-body (body)
  "Scrapes data from a potentially invalid HTML document, returning a list of lists of values."
  (let ((valid-xhtml (chtml:parse body (cxml:make-string-sink))))
    (let ((xhtml-tree (chtml:parse valid-xhtml (cxml-stp:make-builder))))
      (scrape-xhtml xhtml-tree))))

(defun scrape-xhtml (xhtml-tree)
  "Scrapes data from an XHTML tree, returning a list of lists of values."
  (let ((results nil))
    (stp:do-recursively (element xhtml-tree)
            (when (and (typep element 'stp:element)
                   (equal (stp:local-name element) "tr"))
              (if (scrape-row element)
                  (setq results (append results (list (scrape-row element)))))))
    results))

(defun scrape-row (row)
  "Scrapes data from a table row into a list of values."
  (if (equal 4 (stp:number-of-children row))
      (let ((measurement-type (nth-child-data 0 row))
        (measurement-date (nth-child-data 1 row))
        (measurement-value (nth-child-data 2 row)))
    (if (not (equal measurement-type "Measurement"))
        (list measurement-date measurement-value)))))

(defun nth-child-data (number row)
  (stp:data (stp:nth-child 0 (stp:nth-child number row))))

(defun recursive-scrape-page (page-num cookie-jar)
  "Recursively scrapes data from a page and all successive pages.  Returns a list of lists of values."
  (let ((body (get-page page-num cookie-jar)))
    (if body
    (append (scrape-body body)
        (recursive-scrape-page (+ 1 page-num) cookie-jar)))))

(defun show-login-failure ()
  (format t "Login failed.~%"))

(defun write-csv (data csv-pathname)
  "Takes a list of lists of values, converts them to CSV, and writes them to a file."
  (with-open-file (stream csv-pathname 
              :direction :output
              :if-exists :overwrite
              :if-does-not-exist :create)
          (format stream (make-csv data))))

(defun separate-values (value-list)
  "Takes a list of values, and returns a string containing a CSV row that represents the values."
  (format nil "~{~A~^,~}" value-list))

(defun make-csv (list)
  "Takes a list of lists of values, and returns a string containing a CSV file representing each top-level list as a row."
  (let ((csv "")
    (sorted-list (sort list #'first-column-as-date-ascending)))
    (mapcar (lambda (row) (setq csv (concatenate 'string csv (separate-values row) (format nil "~%")))) sorted-list)
    csv))

(defun first-column-as-date-ascending (first-row second-row)
  "Compares two rows by their first column, which is parsed as a time."
  (< (net.telent.date:parse-time (car first-row))
     (net.telent.date:parse-time (car second-row))))

(defun scrape (username password csv-pathname)
  "Attempts to log in, and if successful scrapes all data to the file specified by csv-pathname."
  (let ((cookie-jar (login username password)))
    (if (logged-in? cookie-jar)
    (write-csv (recursive-scrape-page 1 cookie-jar) csv-pathname)
      (show-login-failure))))

(defun main (args)
  "The entry point for the application when compiled with buildapp."
  (if (= (length args) 4)
      (let ((username (nth 1 args))
        (password (nth 2 args))
        (csv-pathname (nth 3 args)))
    (scrape username password csv-pathname))
    (show-usage)))
```

There are several areas I'm unsure about, & would particularly appreciate feedback on:

- use of let & setq (I've got this wrong [in the past](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2135/simple-octal-reader-macro-in-common-lisp))
- structure, naming & comments (as a Lisper, would you like to inherit this codebase?)

The entire app is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/duncan-bayne/myfitnessdata/) if you're interested.

Comment: I always feel interested in every CL projects . Hey thank to your codebase, now I know how to use defpackage :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at defining `asdf` systems instead of using `quicklisp` to load dependencies internally.

The standard way of doing this is to set up an `asd` file. [Here's](http://tychoish.com/rhizome/using-asdf-install-with-sbcl/) a decent walk-through of that process. It's more verbose than `ql:quickload`, but it lets people who don't have quicklisp use your package regardless.

On second thought, screw those guys, keep it up.

---

```
(defun logged-in? (cookie-jar)       
  "Returns true if a cookie-jar contains login information for www.myfitnesspal.com, and nil otherwise."
  (let ((logged-in? nil))
    (loop for cookie in (drakma:cookie-jar-cookies cookie-jar) do
      (if (and (equal (drakma:cookie-name cookie) "known_user")
           (equal (drakma:cookie-domain cookie) "www.myfitnesspal.com")
           (drakma:cookie-value cookie))
          (setq logged-in? t)))
    logged-in?))
```

There's actually a `loop` shorthand for "make sure each member of `list` satisfies `predicate`". The above function can be written as

```
(defun logged-in? (cookie-jar)       
  "Returns true if a cookie-jar contains login information for www.myfitnesspal.com, and nil otherwise."
  (loop for cookie in (drakma:cookie-jar-cookies cookie-jar)
        always (and (equal (drakma:cookie-name cookie) "known_user")
                    (equal (drakma:cookie-domain cookie) "www.myfitnesspal.com"))))
```

---

`foo?` is the Scheme convention for predicates. The common CL conventions are `foop` or `foo-p`. Personally, I prefer `foo?` too, just be aware that it's not standard.

---

```
...
(sorted-list (sort list #'first-column-as-date-ascending)))
...
```

This can get you into trouble. The Common Lisp `sort` should really be named `sort!`, because it's destructive (so `sorted-list` will now contain a sorted list, but `list` won't still be the unsorted list, and isn't guaranteed to be the complete sequence anymore). If you might use `list` again later, instead do

```
...
(sorted-list (sort (copy-list list) #'first-column-as-date-ascending)))
...
```

---

```
(if (search "No measurements found." body)
    nil
    body)
```

Can be written as

```
(unless (search "No measurements found." body) body)
```

---

**EDIT:**

`format` can accept nested iterations in the directive, so you can eliminate `separate-values` by writing `make-csv` as

```
(defun make-csv (list)
  "Takes a list of lists of values, and returns a string containing a CSV file representing each top-level list as a row."
  (let ((sorted-list (sort list #'first-column-as-date-ascending)))
    (format nil "~{~{~A~^,~}~^~%~}" sorted-list)))
```

You could eliminate `make-csv` entirely by putting the above sort+directive directly into `write-csv` (this would also save you a trip through the CSV string, which may or may not make a significant difference).

---

`recursive-scrape-page` can be simplified down to

```
(defun scrape-page (page-num cookie-jar)
  (loop for i from page-num 
    if (get-page i cookie-jar) collect it into pg
      else return pg))
```

As a rule, Common Lisp doesn't guarantee tail-calls the way Scheme does, so it's generally a better idea to use a `loop` than raw recursion. SBCL does support some tail calls, but it isn't guaranteed (though this situation looks simple enough that it just might; do some profiling and compare).

You should be able to simplify `scrape-xhtml` in a similar way to eliminate `(let ((results nil))`.

Note that I haven't tested or profiled any of this since I don't have a "MyFitnessPal" account. Check that it works first.

---

EDIT the Second:

```
 ...
 (let ((valid-xhtml (chtml:parse body (cxml:make-string-sink))))
   (let ((xhtml-tree (chtml:parse valid-xhtml (cxml-stp:make-builder))))
 ...
```

You use this nested let idiom in a couple of places. I assume this is just because the value of `xhtml-tree` depends on the value of `valid-html`. In this case, you can instead write

```
 ...
 (let* ((valid-xhtml (chtml:parse body (cxml:make-string-sink)))
        (xhtml-tree (chtml:parse valid-xhtml (cxml-stp:make-builder))))
 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Be careful to indent your code properly to make it more readable. For instance:

```
(let ((cookie-jar (login username password)))
  (if (logged-in? cookie-jar)
    (write-csv (recursive-scrape-page 1 cookie-jar) csv-pathname)
    (show-login-failure)))
```

That piece of code could by the way possibly be improved by an idiomatic `WITH-VALID-LOGIN` macro (if you want to practice). It could become...

```
(with-valid-login (cookie-jar username password)
  (write-csv (recursive-scrape-page 1 cookie-jar) csv-pathname))
```

...with a macro definition like:

```
(defmacro with-valid-login ((jar user password) &body body)
  `(let ((,jar (login ,user ,password)))
     (if (logged-in? ,jar)
       (progn ,@body)
       (show-login-failure))))
```